# Run time behavior of .NET referenced assembly not existing

Tags: .net, assemblies

Microsoft .NET Framework

```
Assembly A

Assembly B
    Contains Class C - References Assembly A
    Contains Class D - Does not reference Assembly A, Does not reference Class C
```

Questions: 
During runtime if Assembly A DLL does not exist, will Class D be able to execute successfully?
Where as Class C will fail with a reference error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

If you do not deploy `Assembly A` with `Assembly B` and the running code does not call any members of `Assembly A`, then you will not get a runtime error.

In the same case, if you are calling members of `Assembly A`, then you will get a missing reference exception.

Comment: I thought you would get a compile error on the whole application...?

Comment: @Tommy - he is talking about _runtime_. Compile the application, but only distribute one assembly.

Comment: Rgr - misunderstood the question.  Why would someone want to do that again?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about run time. It's a long story of the why... As far as I can tell in my testing so far, I am seeing the same results. Thanks for the info.